# Old Access Update Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, ms-access, sql-update

We recently switched from Oracle to SQL Server and we had this old update statement that used to work but is now giving the error 'operation must be an updateable query'. Well the query type is set to Update, I have tried running it as administrator with no success and we are able to run select statements with no problem, so the connection must be ok?

I'm not sure if I'm just missing something really simple as I'm used to working in SSMS and not Access. The code for the Update statement is below:

```
UPDATE dbo_LEARNER_AIMS 
INNER JOIN dbo_REGISTRATION_UNITS ON dbo_LEARNER_AIMS.RUL_CODE = dbo_REGISTRATION_UNITS.RUL_CODE 
SET dbo_LEARNER_AIMS.END_DATE = [EXP_END_DATE], 
dbo_LEARNER_AIMS.COMPLETION = "10", 
dbo_LEARNER_AIMS.OUTCOME = "40", 
dbo_REGISTRATION_UNITS.FES_PROGRESS_CODE = "EXT", 
dbo_REGISTRATION_UNITS.FES_PROGRESS_DATE = [EXP_END_DATE], 
dbo_REGISTRATION_UNITS.PROGRESS_STATUS = "X"
WHERE (((dbo_LEARNER_AIMS.END_DATE) Is Null)
AND ((dbo_LEARNER_AIMS.FUNDING_YEAR)="17")
AND ((dbo_LEARNER_AIMS.LEARNING_AIM) = [Enter Aim])
AND ((dbo_LEARNER_AIMS.EXP_END_DATE) Between #8/1/2012#
AND [enter expected end date]));
```

Thanks in advance to any answers.

Comment: I have not understood you, are you running this on Access or SQL Server?

Comment: Sorry if I didn't explain it very well - I'm running the update in Access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the error 'operation must be an updateable query'.
almost always means an Indexing problem, usually a missing primary key.
also
check the properties page of the Query, look for the Snapshot vs Dynaset setting.

Comment: It was indeed. The query was updating a view that had no primary key.. I changed it to update data in the relevant table and it worked. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this query :

```
UPDATE dbo_LEARNER_AIMS 

SET END_DATE = [EXP_END_DATE], 
COMPLETION = "10", 
OUTCOME = "40", 
/*
dbo_REGISTRATION_UNITS.FES_PROGRESS_CODE = "EXT", 
dbo_REGISTRATION_UNITS.FES_PROGRESS_DATE = [EXP_END_DATE], 
dbo_REGISTRATION_UNITS.PROGRESS_STATUS = "X"

You can't update multiple table in one update statement ! */

FROM dbo_LEARNER_AIMS  /* add this line */
INNER JOIN dbo_REGISTRATION_UNITS ON dbo_LEARNER_AIMS.RUL_CODE = dbo_REGISTRATION_UNITS.RUL_CODE 

WHERE (((dbo_LEARNER_AIMS.END_DATE) Is Null)
AND ((dbo_LEARNER_AIMS.FUNDING_YEAR)="17")
AND ((dbo_LEARNER_AIMS.LEARNING_AIM) = [Enter Aim])
AND ((dbo_LEARNER_AIMS.EXP_END_DATE) Between #8/1/2012#
AND [enter expected end date]));
```

Comment: Hello there, thanks for your suggestion but I am getting a syntax error in the UPDATE statement when I add the line: FROM dbo_LEARNER_AIMS :-(.

Comment: Hi Tom, how come we could update multiple tables when this query used to update our Oracle tables? +'d your answer for your effort so far.

Comment: I don't know I've never seen this update syntax you described !